FormatMessage returns a char* containing nulls between each character...why?
When translating error messages, I get back a pointer to a string (pMsgBuf) that looks like this:
pMsgBuf = "T\0h\0e\0 \0s\t\0r\0a\0...."

The message is there, but separated by nulls. It has to be a parameter that I am passing to FormatMessage, but have no idea how to fix it.
char* pMsgBuf;
// windows will allocate memory for err string and make our pointer point to it

const DWORD nMsgLen = FormatMessage(
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
    nullptr, hr, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
    reinterpret_cast<LPWSTR>(&pMsgBuf), 0, nullptr
);
// 0 string length returned indicates a failure
if (nMsgLen == 0)
{
    return "Unidentified error code";
}
char joe[100]{};
for (int i = 0, y = 0; i < nMsgLen *2; i++)
{
if (pMsgBuf[i] != '\0')
    joe[y++] = pMsgBuf[i];
    
}
// copy error string from windows-allocated buffer to std::string
std::string errorString = pMsgBuf;
// free windows buffer
size_t size = sizeof(pMsgBuf);
LocalFree(pMsgBuf);
return errorString;


I should have gotten back my string pointer with a trailing null, not each character with a null.
I created a test block to confirm that was what I was getting back from FormatMessage:
char joe[100]{};
for (int i = 0, y = 0; i < nMsgLen *2; i++)
{
    if (pMsgBuf[i] != '\0')
        joe[y++] = pMsgBuf[i];  
}    

Sure enough, Joe the string comes out correctly.

Because it's UTF-16...

Is there a specific reason to avoid std::format? It's more intuitive and much less error-prone.

You are using the Unicode variant of FormatMessage(), which requires a wchar_t* buffer.
Most Win32 API functions have a "W" and an "A" variant, and the plain name #defines to one of them, depending on compiler settings. So, in your case, FormatMessage resolves to FormatMessageW.
Generally, in Windows, do use Unicode and all strings should be std::wstring and wchar_t. Use char/std::string with WideCharToMultiByte with CP_UTF8 for conversions suitable for UTF-8 transmission, say, web post data.
If you use the "A" version, Windows internally converts everything to UTF-16 according to the system setting's local codepage for non-Unicode apps. This in recent Windows may be UTF-8, but don't rely on it, it's a global administrator setting.

In addition, UTF-16 copies Latin-1 in the code range 0x00-0xff, which in turn copies ASCII for the 0x00-0x7f range. Which is why English texts appear as "usual" in a hexdump, except for the 0-bytes between the letters because it's a 16-bit code -- it doesn't really matter what encoding gets used, it's always the same numbers.

You have your project settings set to Unicode, so FormatMessage() is actually calling FormatMessageW(), which outputs a UTF-16 wchar_t string. But you are using a char* pointer to receive it, so you are seeing the raw bytes. ASCII characters in UTF-16 have their high byte set to 0.
You need to use a wchar_t* pointer instead:
wchar_t* pMsgBuf;

FormatMessage(..., reinterpret_cast<LPWSTR>(&pMsgBuf), ...); 

Otherwise, if you want the error message output as a char string, you can call FormatMessageA() directly:
char* pMsgBuf;

FormatMessageA(..., reinterpret_cast<LPSTR>(&pMsgBuf), ...); 

